# How to change Hybris server's port

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

The default port is `http://localhost:9001`.

How do I run the hybris platform using another port?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a **/config/*local.properties*** file with this content:

```
tomcat.http.port=9101 
tomcat.ssl.port=9102 
tomcat.ajp.port=8109
tomcat.jmx.port=9103 
tomcat.jmx.server.port=9104
```

Then you'll get Hybris server to run on `http://localhost:9101`.

Answer (score 15):

Edit your **{HYBRIS_ROOT_DIR}/config/local.properties** file and use the following properties to configure the various ports:

```
tomcat.http.port=9001
tomcat.ssl.port=9002
tomcat.ajp.port=8009
tomcat.jmx.port=9003
tomcat.jmx.server.port=9004
```

You can find the complete configuration reference on the Hybris wiki here: https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Configuration+Properties+Reference

In order for the changes to be applied you must run ant and restart Hybris.

You can run **ant all**, but if you have only changed the configuration you can deploy these changes without having to re-compile by using **ant deploy** which is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the port, make sure you update the spring security `port-mapping`s (should be already using the configuration service and these properties via Spring EL to do this if you're on a recent version of hybris), and, for local development, the site URL resolution (`website.<x>.http(s)`, `media.<x>.http(s)`) properties and the CMS Site URL mapping regular expressions (ImpEx or hMC). There's also a property for jvdbc I think.

You can change these in the `config/local.properties`, `platform/project.properties` or a custom extension's `project.properties`. The `local.properties` file has the highest priority (if the property is defined in multiple places), then the custom extension's `project.properties`, and finally in the platform's `project.properties`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above configuration provided by Zathrus Writer. You might have to add the solr port configuration to have say two instances of hybris running in the same server.

```
solrserver.instances.default.port=8986
```

Full configuration:

```
tomcat.http.port=9201
tomcat.ssl.port=9202
tomcat.ajp.port=8209
tomcat.jmx.port=9203
tomcat.jmx.server.port=9204
solrserver.instances.default.port=8986
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as well

```
hybris.instance.id=60
tomcat.http.port=9${hybris.instance.id}1
tomcat.ssl.port=9${hybris.instance.id}2
tomcat.jmx.port=9${hybris.instance.id}3
tomcat.debug.port=9${hybris.instance.id}0
tomcat.jmx.server.port=9${hybris.instance.id}4
tomcat.ajp.port=9${hybris.instance.id}5
```

Comment: That's a rather odd approach... Why would you want each node in your cluster listening on different ports?!

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you may face with another port issue cause debug port.
You should also change it.

Please use;

```
tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=n
```

Answer (score 1):

Override port configurations in {HYBRIS_ROOT_DIR}/config/local.properties file.

```
tomcat.http.port=9011
tomcat.ssl.port=9012
tomcat.ajp.port=8019
tomcat.jmx.port=9013
tomcat.jmx.server.port=9014
```

In addition to the port we can also override xmx values of JVM in tomcat.generaloptions configurations in config/local.properties as listed below.

```
tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx6G -XX:MaxPermSize=300M -ea -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_init_tomcat.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As SAP Hybris runs on tomcat server, we can run as many servers as needed simultaneously based on our memory.

We need to configure in **config/local.properties**

- To run tomcat in different port

> tomcat.http.port=6001 
> tomcat.ssl.port=6002 
> tomcat.ajp.port=6009
> tomcat.jmx.port=6003
> tomcat.jmx.server.port=6004
> os.rmiregistry.port=3198
> website.electronics.http=http://electronics.local:6001/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.electronics.https=https://electronics.local:6002/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.apparel-de.http=http://apparel-de.local:6001/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.apparel-de.https=https://apparel-de.local:6002/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.apparel-uk.http=http://apparel-uk.local:6001/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.apparel-uk.https=https://apparel-uk.local:6002/yacceleratorstorefront
> website.powertools.http=http://powertools.local:6001/yb2bacceleratorstorefront
> website.powertools.https=https://powertools.local:6002/yb2bacceleratorstorefront

- To Run Solr in separate port

> solrserver.instances.default.port=6983

- To have debug in separate port

> tomcat.debugjavaoptions=-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT,CLDR -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=6000,suspend=n